# sql, limiting the hours

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Hie, 
i have been working on a simple data set like

```
no  Date                        time_in             time_out       extrahours
1   2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000 09:00:00.0000000    18:50:00.0000000    0
1   2018-05-02 00:00:00.0000000 08:00:00.0000000    20:00:00.0000000    3
1   2018-05-03 00:00:00.0000000 09:50:00.0000000    19:50:00.0000000    1
1   2018-05-04 00:00:00.0000000 07:00:00.0000000    17:45:00.0000000    1
1   2018-05-05 00:00:00.0000000 09:15:00.0000000    13:50:00.0000000    -5
1   2018-05-06 00:00:00.0000000 08:45:00.0000000    23:55:00.0000000    6
1   2018-05-07 00:00:00.0000000 12:00:00.0000000    23:00:00.0000000    2
1   2018-05-08 00:00:00.0000000 02:30:00.0000000    23:55:00.0000000    12
1   2018-05-09 00:00:00.0000000 10:50:00.0000000    19:50:00.0000000    0
1   2018-05-10 00:00:00.0000000 08:36:00.0000000    19:50:00.0000000    2
```

i was asked to limit the maximum number of extra hours within 2, that is the extra hours have to be compensated for a weekend on (Saturday or Sunday)

extra hours 
0
0
0
0
0(sat)
2
2
2
2
2
if he works on Saturdays and Sundays for 9 hours then the extra hours is processed for over time else they are compensated.

please do take time to answer my question thanks.

Comment: can you please more elobrate your question,including with your desired output and what you have tried so far !!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make a `CASE WHEN`, to see if your hours are dividable by 2, which they should be as long as they are bigger than 0.

You then take your hours and divide them by 2 to get your two different hours. You can use the mysql `HOUR()` function to achieve this.

When that is done, you convert your result back into time using the `SEC_TO_TIME()` function and multiply correspondingly to get whichever time format your want, 60 for minutes, then another 60 for hours.

I used the `MINUTE()` function to get the minutes, and went on with the same approach as with the hours.

I came up with something like this:

```
SELECT
  empNo,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN
        extraHours > 0
      THEN
        SEC_TO_TIME(((HOUR(extraHours) / 2)*60)*60)
      END) as otOne,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN
        extraHours > 0
      THEN
        SEC_TO_TIME(((HOUR(extraHours) / 2)*60)*60)
      END) as otTwo,
  SEC_TO_TIME(MINUTE(extraHours)*60) as otThree
FROM
  tbl_time
```

[Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c16b/38)

If you want an extra field with seconds, you simply use the same approach, and use the `SECOND()` function.

*This answer is mostly in regard to your other question that got marked as a duplicate.*